# Is the max skill of retail dream job bitizen only 8?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have cycled through 500 bitizens (using a tower bux to move them in, and then evicting after) in order to try and get bitizens with a dream job and skill level 9 into each job slot, but I have not seen a bitizen with a skill of 9 in retail (purple) yet. Not even in bitizens that have other dream jobs. Is retail capped at a skill of 8, or am I just extremely unlucky so far?

Comment: I just checked all of my retail levels (I have 4 at the moment), and the max level of any bitizen is 8 across all of them.  Definitely a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just really unlucky so far. Here is a photo of Watto's Wares with three skill 9 bitizen with a dream job star. In addition I have two other bitizens that want Watto's Wares as their dream job, but it is already full.I was playing this on an iPad Mini, so your problem may be a device related bug.

[image]

Comment: Just an addendum: Jacen appears to be playing on iOS. Numerous people have reported on Android to never receive skill 9 Retail bitizens.

Answer (score 7):

You're not alone. I'm 60 levels in, I've gone through hundreds of bitizens and haven't seen a single retail level 9 yet. This is on the Android version, fwiw, so I'm assuming it's a bug. This game has tons of them.

Answer (score 6):

Retail is definitely capped at 8 in my tower as well.  Every single bitizen that has ever visited has had an 8 or less in retail only.

Randomness can not explain it considering the amount of people I've moved in and out.   It's possibly a bug related to a particular device if they are showing up for some people.  I'm using a Nexus 4.

Comment: Mine was on an iPad Mini, so that is possible.

Comment: Someone else I talked to who is not having this issue was playing on an iPhone.  Perhaps an Android issue that isn't present on iOS.

Comment: That would make sense. Tiny Death Star still has a lot of bugs.

Comment: On my PC, I have several level 9 retail bitizens. So it could just be RNGods are just messing with you.

Comment: To add my data: I have plenty of level 9's for all industries, although I have a disproportionate number of yellow 8s.  This is iOS.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's definitely capped at 8 for some devices!  I think for mine retail can only be even numbers because of about 200 I've checked, they've all only been 8, 6, 4, 2, or 0.  I'm using Android on a Galaxy S3.  I hope they fix this bug soon so I can have a perfect tiny death star...

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug with the Android version. Not only is there no "level 9" but I looked and all of my Retail citizens have an even number in their job skill, 8 of course being the highest.... so not only are there no "level 9" Retailers in the Android version, there are no "level 7,5,3 or 1" either.

Answer (score 0):

I too have had several level 9 Retail Bitizens, though it does feel as though there are significantly fewer. I'm playing the Android version of the game on a Samsung Galaxy III.

EDIT: I have to backtrack on this. I misremembered having anyone over 8, and i haven't acquired any since then, even after the holiday update. It looks like, on Androids at least, there are no level 9 retail skills.