# Does the 1.3.0 update fix the Android retail dream job bitizen max level bug?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Prior to the 1.3.0 release on 2/6/14, there was a bug on Android where the highest level you could get for a bitizen whose dream job was a retail floor was 8.

I want to know if you are now able to obtain a bitizen whose dream job is a retail floor with a level of 9 instead of 8 as a result of this update.

Comment: Is this a known bug, or is it just bad luck?

Comment: Duplicate, perhaps: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142391/is-the-max-skill-of-retail-dream-job-bitizen-only-8

Comment: It's not bad luck.  On my android version, not a single bitizen ever has had an odd retail skill level.  However, as of last Sunday my tower is full of people all in their dream jobs, and with skills of 8 or 9, so I would have to evict someone to test, and I'm not going to do that!  This question is not a duplicate, as they are asking about the upgrade that went out yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

No.  In fact, you should not update with that update, as it introduces a number of new bugs.  As of this posting, there is no patch or fixed update.

There are more details here: [How do I claim or complete new Imperial assignments?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155099/how-do-i-claim-or-complete-new-imperial-assignments/164531#164531)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, played most of the morning. Still just even numbers.