# Menu Not Saving/Cannot finish assignments

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Noticed two problems making my game nearly unplayable.

I cannot "finish" any of my assignments as when I click finish, I simply get a tutorial telling me about the assignments. So I turn of the assignments in the menu, this does nothing as the menu options refuse to save. All of my holograms are green, indicating they are done, but I can't "finish" them.

What am I to do? Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that about turning off the assignments in the menu.  What platform are you playing on?  Also, have you tried to exit the game and reopen it.  This cures a great many problems.

Comment: Someone else had this issue: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155099/how-do-i-claim-or-complete-new-imperial-assignments?rq=1 but it doesn't look like it was solved... are you also on android?. Usually exiting and reopening the app works as David said.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8 (I know, I know...). I close it and restart it, and it still does the same thing. Also, I have the same issue that this person described.

Answer (score 1):

If your game version is 1.4.1, then this is a known bug with the first 2014 update.  You can read more about it here: [How do I claim or complete new Imperial assignments?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155099/how-do-i-claim-or-complete-new-imperial-assignments/164531#164531)